# Как распечатать защищенные (protected) свойства модели Eloquent Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

При распечатке экземпляра Eloquent:

```
$model= new App\Post;
$post=$model->find(1);
var_dump($post);
```

есть такие свойства, например

```
["table":protected]=>
  string(4) "post"
["fillable":protected]=>
  array(21) {
   [0]=>
   string(7) "id_user"
   [1]=>
   string(7) "id_post"
   [2]=>
   string(10) "created_at"
   [3]=>
   string(10) "updated_at"
   [4]=>
   string(4) "city"
}
```

и еще много других, которых я почему-то не могу вывести:

```
var_dump($post->table);
```

Почему? И можно ли от них избавиться и оставить только ["attributes":protected] и их распечатывать, если мне нужны только значения полей таблицы, а все остальное не нужно?

Comment: И зачем распечатывать защищенные свойства?

Comment: Чтобы обратиться к ним

Comment: Распечатать чтобы обратиться, что?

Comment: Например, мне нужен массив свойств fillable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для дебага используй хелперы `dump($variable)` или `dd($variable)`. Они тебе покажут всю суть переданных переменных - массивов, объектов или скалярных переменных.

А вообще твой подход в корне неверный. Ну нафига* тебе использовать защищенное свойство модели??? Оно же для этого и является защищенным, потому что используется только во внутренней реализации. 
Нужно название таблицы? пожалуйста - пользуйся геттером модели `$model->getTable()`. Почитай про внутреннее устройство моделей. А вообще лучше сначала изучи PHP, его синтаксис, принципы ООП, а потом изучай фреймворк (по документации)

Comment: Я уже пишу, изучать нет времени...